# Rotate object on Y axis in winrt

Tags: windows-runtime

How to Rotate a Rectangle on Y axis, CompositeTransform and Rotate Transform has only X Axis rotation method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Projection property and assign a PlanarProjection value. It's pretty front and center when you edit it in Blend.

EDIT* Example

```
<TextBlock
    Text="Hello"
    FontSize="96"
    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
    VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <TextBlock.Projection>
        <PlaneProjection
            RotationY="45"/>
    </TextBlock.Projection>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: Can u please give any example of this?? Please